# Exception "LP_OVERLAPPED instance instead of pointer to OVERLAPPED" in PyFilesystem

Tags: python-3.x

We use PyFilesystem in our project. It works fine on Windows 7 x64 but on Windows 7 x32 it raises an exception:

```
Exception in thread Thread-28:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 911, in _bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
   File "C:\environment\lib\site-packages\fs\osfs\watch_win32.py", line 365, in run
     -1)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 4: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_OVERLAPPED instance instead of pointer to OVERLAPPED
```

Code where the exception occurs:

```
...
overlapped = OVERLAPPED()
while not self.closed:
    try:
        GetQueuedCompletionStatus(self._iocp,
                                  ctypes.byref(nbytes),
                                  ctypes.byref(iocpkey),
                                  ctypes.byref(overlapped),
                                  -1)
    except WindowsError:
        traceback.print_exc()
    ...
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was caused by having a other module in that case `watchdog` defining args for the same function. I suggest to print out `GetQueuedCompletionStatus.argtypes`. This will give you a hint with which module `PyFilesystem` is conflicting.

My output was in that case:

`(<class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>, <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>, <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>, <class 'watchdog.observers.winapi.LP_OVERLAPPED'>, <class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>)`

Where the 4th arg is pointing to `watchdog.observers.winapi.LP_OVERLAPPED`, which leads you to your problem.